# Validar token valido en laravel

Tags: laravel, oauth2

necesito ayudita, lo que sucede es que queremos validar que cuando un token este inactivo y/o ingresando cualquier dato que no sea el token correcto, que retorne un json diciendo {"msj: "token no valido"} y no un error de laravel como este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo de laravel en api.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('signup', 'AuthController@signup');  
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {

        Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
        Route::get('user', 'AuthController@user');
        Route::post('recibir', 'CustomController@recibe');
        Route::get('feedback', 'CustomController@feedback');

    });

});
```

se agradece, saludos y feliz 2021

Comment: Ahí es una exception de que la vista login no existe, debes implementarla o en el middleware captura el evento cuando el request sea por api y retornas un mensaje, o tambien puedes manejar la exception comprobando con un instanceof y el nombre de esa exeption, en este caso como usas middleware de api lo que hace es redirigir a la vista login cuando no pasa la validacion, otra solucion es sobrescribir los metodos de guards en el middleware

Comment: Te recomiendo ocupar Middleware para ello, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware

Answer (score 0):

Pues yo hice lo siguiente, no sé si es lo mejor, pero a mí me funciona de maravilla:

busca el archivo *app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php* y edítalo

```
 protected function redirectTo($request)
 {
     if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
       return route('login'); // Eliminas esta linea
      return route('api.unauthorized'); //Añades esta
     }
 }
```

Lo que hice fue sustituir la ruta de retorno cuando el Token no es válido. La ruta quedo de la siguiente forma:

```
Route::get('unauthorized',function(Request $r){
    return response()->json(["Mensaje"=>"No autorizado, No se proporcionó Token o es invalido"],401);
   })->name('api.unauthorized');
?>
```